# ¿Por qué en este ejemplo hay que usar innerHTML si el valor ya ha sido especificado anteriormente?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy siguiendo un tutorial dónde, entre otras cosas, dentro de una función se quiere obtener el valor de cada < li > dentro de un < ul >

```html
<ul id="nombres" class="collection with-header">
            <li class="collection-header">
                <h5>A</h5>
            </li>
            <li class="collection-item">
                <a href="#">Abe</a>
            </li>
            <li class="collection-item">
                <a href="#">Adan</a>
            </li>
            <li class="collection-item">
                <a href="#">Ana</a>
            </li>
            <li class="collection-item">
                <a href="#">Abram</a>
            </li>
```

Concretamente se quiere obtener los nombres (Abe, Adan, Ana, Abram) para luego hacer algo con ellos.

El tutorial sigue estos pasos (los comentarios los he añadido yo para que se entienda mi duda mejor)

```js
function filtrarNombres(){
  var ul = document.getElementById("nombres");
   // ↓ Aquí saca los <li> correcto?
  var li = nombres.querySelectorAll("li.collection-item");
  
  for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++){
  // ↓Aquí al específicar [0] ya ha sacado el nombre de cada <a>,no?
  let a = li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
  // ↓ Entonces por qué aquí tiene que decir "innerHTML" de cada <a>
  if(a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filtroNombre)){

        } else {

        }
```

Podéis Ignorar lo demás de UpperCase y indexOf, en lo que estoy confuso es en por qué hay que especificar innerHTML si supuestamente el "li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];" ya debería haber sacado el nombre.

Answer (score 2):

Quizá puede ser interesante ver lo que estás seleccionado para poder comprender lo que pasa.

Primero haces esto:

```
  var li = nombres.querySelectorAll("li.collection-item");
```

Si imprimimos en la consola con `console.log(li);` obtendremos:

```
{
  "0": <li class="collection-item">…</li>,
  "1": <li class="collection-item">…</li>,
  "2": <li class="collection-item">…</li>,
  "3": <li class="collection-item">…</li>,
  "length": 4,
  "item": function item() {
    [native code]
},
  "entries": function entries() {
    [native code]
},
  "forEach": function forEach() {
    [native code]
},
  "keys": function keys() {
    [native code]
},
  "values": function values() {
    [native code]
}
}
```

Esto `"0": <li class="collection-item">…</li>` ... expresa que están todos tus `li` incluyendo los anchor tags. Y ya eso nos hace pensar que **refinando un poco más la selección podremos alcanzar los anchor tags sin dar tantas vueltas** (ver solución propuesta al final).

Bien, bien.

Luego, en tu lógica vas a recorrer todos tus `li`, para encontrar los anchor tag que hay en ellos mediante: `let a = li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];` ojo, ese código corre dentro de un bucle que va iterando sobre la lista de `li`. El resultado si lo imprimimos en consola, es este:

```
<a href="#">Abe</a>
<a href="#">Adan</a>
<a href="#">Ana</a>
<a href="#">Abram</a>
```

**Estamos pues ante cada elemento `a`, pero no tenemos el texto que éste contiene**, porque [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) devuelve:

> ... una `HTMLCollection` en vivo de elementos con el nombre de
>   etiqueta dado.

Una [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) es definida como:

> La interfaz `HTMLCollection` representa una colección genérica (objeto
>   tipo array similar a arguments) de elementos (en orden de documento) y
>   ofrece métodos y propiedades para seleccionarlos de la lista.

Si quitamos el índice `0`, veremos en efecto una `HTMLCollection`. Si imprimimos `let a = li[i].getElementsByTagName('a');`, obtenemos:

```
{
  "0": <a href="#">Abe</a>,
  "length": 1,
  "item": function item() {
    [native code]
},
  "namedItem": function namedItem() {
    [native code]
}
}
{
  "0": <a href="#">Adan</a>,
  "length": 1,
  "item": function item() {
    [native code]
},
  "namedItem": function namedItem() {
    [native code]
}
}
{
  "0": <a href="#">Ana</a>,
  "length": 1,
  "item": function item() {
    [native code]
},
  "namedItem": function namedItem() {
    [native code]
}
}
{
  "0": <a href="#">Abram</a>,
  "length": 1,
  "item": function item() {
    [native code]
},
  "namedItem": function namedItem() {
    [native code]
}
}
```

O sea, en el índice `0` tienes el elemento `anchor` en sí, pero no el dato que hay dentro de él.

Si quieres seleccionar el texto directamente, puedes hacer esto dentro del bucle:

```
let a = li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].text;
```

o

```
let a = li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].textContent;
```

o

```
let a = li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML;
```

**PERO** esto no funcionará correctamente si hubiera más de un elemento `<a>` en alguno de lo `li`, porque `getElementsByTagName` lo que hace es devolver una colección de elementos con ese tag indexados a manera de array. En ese caso, para acceder al texto de un hipotético segundo anchor tendrás que irlo a buscar de este modo `li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[1]`. En cambio, con `querySelectorAll` del modo indicado a continuación, son alcanzados todos los elementos `<a>` que existan en los `li`.

---

### En resumen y ... Propuesta de solución

Que estás mareando demasiado las cosas, que estás dando demasiadas vueltas, que estás mezclando criterios de selección (generalmente, cuando usas `querySelectorAll` no necesitas combinarlo con `getElementsBy*`).

¿Por qué no hacer algo así, sencillamente?:

```js
filtrarNombres();

function filtrarNombres() {
  var ul = document.getElementById("nombres");
  var allAnchors = nombres.querySelectorAll("li.collection-item a");
  allAnchors.forEach(function(elem) {
    console.log(elem.text.toUpperCase());
  });
}
```

```html
<ul id="nombres" class="collection with-header">
  <li class="collection-header">
    <h5>A</h5>
  </li>
  <li class="collection-item">
    <a href="#">Abe</a>
  </li>
  <li class="collection-item">
    <a href="#">Adan</a>
  </li>
  <li class="collection-item">
    <a href="#">Ana</a>
  </li>
  <li class="collection-item">
    <a href="#">Abram</a>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

`li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0]` devuelve un [Elemento](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) (no confundir con un [Nodo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node)), en este caso, de tipo [Anchor](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement).

En este caso, estás recogiendo todos los elementos `a` de ese `li` y, especificando el índice `[0]`, recoges el primero de esos elementos. Por lo que estás tratando con un elemento. A partir de este punto, si quieres recoger o setear su contenido html, puedes usar `.innerHTML`. Si quieres recoger o setear únicamente el texto plano del elemento, puedes usar `.innerText`.

Answer (score 0):

Con la función `getElementsByTagName()` lo que obtienes es un `array` con los elementos que le pases como parámetro a la función. A través de ese elemento puedes acceder a sus atributos, propiedades y contenido. Al igual que usarías la función `getAttribute()` para obtener, por ejemplo, el `href` de la etiqueta `<a>`, también debes especificar que lo que quieres obtener del elemento es el contenido **HTML**. Para ello se usa la propiedad `innerHTML`

**Referencias:** 
[innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), 
[getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)

Answer (score 0):

Correcto , eso `li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];` ya saca el elemento `a` con el nombre que buscas .
Pero eso if no hace eso sino que para lo que sirve ese if es para aplicar un filtro a eso nombre .
Con la función indexOf evalúas si existe un caracter en mayusculas  `filtroNombre` en ese  nombre .
Es decir si por ejemplo `filtroNombre ='N'` entonces en el if solo entraran los nombres que tengan una `n` o `N`

```js
var ul = document.getElementById("nombres");
// ↓ Aquí saca los <li> correcto?
var li = nombres.querySelectorAll("li.collection-item");
var filtroNombre = 'N';
for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  // ↓Aquí al específicar [0] ya ha sacado el nombre de cada <a>,no?
  let a = li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
  // ↓ Entonces por qué aquí tiene que decir "innerHTML" de cada <a>
  console.log(a.innerHTML);
  if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filtroNombre) != -1) {
    console.log('TRUE ');
  } else {
    console.log('FASLE ');
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nombres" class="collection with-header">
  <li class="collection-header">
    <h5>A</h5>
  </li>
  <li class="collection-item">
    <a href="#">Abe</a>
  </li>
  <li class="collection-item">
    <a href="#">Adan</a>
  </li>
  <li class="collection-item">
    <a href="#">Ana</a>
  </li>
  <li class="collection-item">
    <a href="#">Abram</a>
  </li>

</ul>
```